# react npm run build command failed and gives error Failed to compile. Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, build

I am creating production build where I am facing this issue while running command **npm run build**. it gives me below error
While I tried to increase heap size by adding this line --max_old_space_size=4096 to the build in the package.json.
I also tried to remove node_modules and then clear cache and install node_modules again but it still failed.

> Note -> application running in development mode no error no issue at all.

> Node version v14.17.3  npm version 6.14.13

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Maximum call stack size exceeded


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MySystem\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-08T10_32_42_442Z-debug.log
```

*C:\Users\MySystem\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-09-08T10_32_42_442Z-debug.log*

Below are this url logs

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~prebuild: my-app@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: my-app@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Users\MySystem\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\MySystem\Documents\project\televisit-main\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\MySystem\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\MySystem\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\MySystem\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\MySystem\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\MySystem\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2022.1\bin;;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\MySystem\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs
9 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\MySystem\Documents\project\televisit-main
10 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: my-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MySystem\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MySystem\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-app@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\MySystem\Documents\project\televisit-main
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.17.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error my-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: did you try removing package-lock.json together with the node_modules folder?

Comment: Yes I removed package.json and then install again but it didnt work

Comment: Well now I resolved the issue. The issue is with css file in my project I wrote some line in css file and which were not css code but then I forogt to comment that. Well after debugging file by file I reach to my code and then my mind stuck how a single in css file waste my 3days.

Comment: Well after three days debugging I finally got the code where it breaks and gives me error.

It was really hard to debug but after checking file to file I got the breaking lines of code. I copied it from somewhere and paste it without going through it.

> below are the CSS code in a file that was breaking the build


    .t-d-b {
      display: block;
    }
    ------------------------------------------------------------- * ::after,
    ::before {
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }